# mysql - Alter Unique Key

Tags: mysql

I am new to this, so I will try to explain as best I can. I have a UNIQUE key in a table that I am looking to alter it by adding another column.

So, I have a UNIQUE key - UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2. My goal is to DROP this key and create a new one called - UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2_column3. Also, I am looking to make sure this can be run over and over again if needed.

I have the basic sql down, `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP index UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2`, will DROP the original key. And then `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2_column3 UNIQUE (column1,column2,column3)` will add the new I need.

What I would like to do is put this in some sort of IF/IF EXISTS THEN statement, where IF EXISTS UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2 THEN DROP UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2 AND ADD UNIQUE_tablename_column1_column2_column3.

Any ideas, help and assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you need to write such logic in a stored procedure, since IF/ELSE constructions only work in stored programs.

Here are two example scripts I use regularly to drop and create indexes, checking first for existence. It supports any kind of index (UNIQUE or non-unique).

```
-- Use to create indexes via a CALL statement. Be sure to use DELIMITER when creating these
-- procedures on your system:

    CREATE PROCEDURE `admin_create_index`(
        index_name VARCHAR(64),    
        column_list VARCHAR(64),   
        table_name VARCHAR(64),
        is_unique TINYINT(1),
        db_name  VARCHAR(64)
    )
    BEGIN
    SET @sqlexec := 
    CONCAT
    (
        'SELECT @i := COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE INDEX_NAME = \'',
        index_name, 
        '\' AND TABLE_NAME = \'', 
        table_name,
        '\' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = \'',
        db_name,
        '\''
    );

    SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
    PREPARE lookup FROM @sqlexec;
    EXECUTE lookup;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE lookup;

    IF @i = 0 THEN
        SET @sqlexec := CONCAT('CREATE ', IF(is_unique > 0, 'UNIQUE ', ''), 'INDEX ', index_name, ' ON `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '`(', column_list, ')');
        SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
        PREPARE statement FROM @sqlexec;
        EXECUTE statement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
        SELECT CONCAT('Successful execution of: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT('Warning: Index `', index_name, '` already exists on `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '`') AS 'Warning';
    END IF;
    END;

-- Use to drop an index (if it exists):

CREATE PROCEDURE `admin_drop_index`(
    index_name VARCHAR(64),    
    table_name VARCHAR(64),
    db_name  VARCHAR(64)
)
BEGIN
SET @sqlexec := 
CONCAT
(
    'SELECT @i := COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE INDEX_NAME = \'',
    index_name, 
    '\' AND TABLE_NAME = \'', 
    table_name,
    '\' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = \'',
    db_name,
    '\''
);

SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
PREPARE lookup FROM @sqlexec;
EXECUTE lookup;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE lookup;

IF @i > 0 THEN
    SET @sqlexec := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '` DROP INDEX `', index_name, '`');
    SELECT CONCAT('Executing: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
    PREPARE statement FROM @sqlexec;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
    SELECT CONCAT('Successful execution of: "', @sqlexec, '"') AS 'Info';
ELSE
    SELECT CONCAT('Warning: Index `', index_name, '` does not exist on `', db_name, '`.`', table_name, '`') AS 'Warning';
END IF;

END;
```

And here are the example CALL statements:

```
CALL admin_create_index('my_index_name', 'col_name_a, col_name_b', 'table_name', TRUE, DATABASE());

CALL admin_drop_index('my_index_name', 'table_name', DATABASE());
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I will have to give this a try and report back!